# How to fetch data from URL in laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes

As a response from a payment gateway, I got redirection to my URL like:

```
https://app.example.com/?cko-payment-token=pay_tok_45333-23232-4705-8788787-d8f451476553
```

I use Laravel and how I can get `pay_tok_45333-23232-4705-8788787-d8f451476553`

and use it. A Route for this needs to be like?

Comment: how to handle this URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` params are just normal query params. You can get them using

`$request->input('cko-payment-token')` or `request()->input('cko-payment-token')`

Comment: Minor note: If you want to make sure it came from the URL (and not, say, `POST` data) you can use `$request->query('cko-payment-token')` instead. In most cases, it's not necessary. Similarly, `$request->post()` will get POST data, even if there's a matching GET parameter with the same name.

Comment: What if the URL is https://app.example.com/3d?cko-payment-token=pay_tok_45333-23232-4705-8788787-d8f451476553 ?

Comment: @AleksPer Doesn't change a thing. It's still a query parameter, regardless of what route it's on. Your route would be something like `Route::get('3d', ...)`; the `$request->input()` call would be identical.